# In Google App Maker, how do I update a label to show the current time?

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I update the time shown in a text label in Google App Maker to show the current time?

I am creating a sign-in / sign-out kiosk and I want to show the current date and time on the screen, as shown here.

[image]

The date and time are specified in the "onAttach" event script for the label:

```
var options = {  
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long",  
    day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "2-digit"  
};

var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options, {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});
widget.text = currentDateTime;
```

However, this label is only updated when the page loads and there isn't an event option to periodically run a script to update the time.  I'm hoping there is a solution that doesn't require a server script or creating a new datasource, however, that may be necessary.

Any help appreciated!

**Update to Question.**

Upon further research, I see others have used SetInterval to periodically call a function.  I updated my script with a SetInterval function.  This appears to work, however, my research also found some people thought SetInterval wasn't always a good choice.  I don't know enough about it to judge it at this point but I'll update this post if I learn more.

```
function getCurrentDateTime() {
  var options = {  
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long",  
    day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "2-digit" 
};

var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options, {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});
widget.text = currentDateTime;
}
getCurrentDateTime();
var interval = setInterval(getCurrentDateTime, 60000);
```

Comment: setInterval is the right choice here. All you have to do is to clear the interval when they navigate away from the page and set it again when the page loads.

Comment: I think the reference to not use setInterval is only for cases when a server script needs to finish before something happens on the client. In that type of case you should use success and failure functions but your case is totally fine using setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the confirmation that using setInterval is appropriate.  Also appreciate the tip on clearing the interval when users navigate away from the page.  I think I have a solution for that.  The approach I have used is

1. Define a custom property for the page called setIntervalIDNumber
2. Initiate the setInterval function with the onAttach event and
   store the setInterval number in the setIntervalIDNumber property
3. Clear the setInterval function by referencing the
   setIntervalIDNumber property

Here's the code:

onAttach:

```
function getCurrentDateTime() {
  var options = {  
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long",  
    day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "2-digit" 
};

var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options, {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});
widget.text = currentDateTime;
}
getCurrentDateTime();
widget.root.properties.setIntervalIDNumber = setInterval(getCurrentDateTime, 60000);
```

onDetach:

```
clearInterval(widget.root.properties.setIntervalIDNumber);
```

I think that might be the final solution.